# Firebase Update Method Does Not Update Value When Called Multiple Times On Different Nodes But Return OnComplete Successfully

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am Trying To Update the status of Order In My App. When Page Refreshes and I try to Update it, It successfully Update. But When I try to Update Some Other Order, Update Method Return Success on OnComplete Method But Does Not Update Data On Real Time Database.
Its causing me headaches, I have Already Tried All Possible Solutions but nothing worked.

```
var dbRef = firebase.database();
var requestsRef = dbRef.ref('requests');
var onComplete = function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Synchronization failed');
    } else {
        console.log('Synchronization succeeded');
    }
};

function sendToProcessing(e) {
    var confirmation = confirm("Really Wanna Send To Processing?");
    if (confirmation) {
        var key = parseInt($(e).data("key"));
        requestsRef.child(key).update({
            'status': "Processing"
        }, onComplete);
        $('#orderDetailsModel').modal("hide")

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML Part:

```
<button type="button" class="btn m-2 btn-outline-success " onclick="sendToProcessing(this)" id="btn-processing"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></button>
```

Image Display:
[image]

Image Model When Clicked On Eye Button
[image]

Answer (score 0):

your are trying to retrieve key using $(e).data("Key"). And in your case e is the button element. The button element doesn't have any attribute called data-key.

Try adding your key to the button as below.

`<button type="button" class="btn m-2 btn-outline-success "  data-key="keyvalue "onclick="sendToProcessing(this)" id="btn-processing"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></button>`

Also try debugging your sendToProcessing Method, and try to console.log(key) which might be a null.

Comment: actually, i am adding it using Javascript

Comment: Here Is My Complete Code paste.ofcode.org/ekcSBrHR63aPEuCpeW6ux3

Comment: In your code change the line as below in sendToProcessing  Method.  var key = parseInt($(e).attr("data-key")). The $(e).data() doesn't  retrieve dynamically added data attributes.

Comment: var key = parseInt($(e).attr("data-key")) is returning NaN

Comment: Looks to me like, it worked. Is your firebase child key a number??. Returning Nan tells me your key has non-numeric values. If that's the case you can safely remove parseInt from the above line and re-write it as var key  = $(e).attr("data-key");